# My MVC application couldn't recognize the database connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

In my mvc application, everything was working fine before but when i made some changes (the database name, user id & password) in the Connection string in the App.Config, my application is not recognizing anymore the database connection.

```
<!-- DEVELOPPEMENT ORIOLIS -->
<add name="DEAXIMAEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DeAximaDataModel.csdl|res://*/DeAximaDataModel.ssdl|res://*/DeAximaDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=AXIMADB;persist security info=True;user id=****;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

it shows me the error like this everywhere i'm using my database connnection variable

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DAL;
using System;
using MvcAppDE.Fonctions;
using MvcAppDE.Filters;

namespace MvcAppDE.Controllers
{
    [IsRegisteredUser]
    public class HomeController : Commun.BaseController
    {
//it doesn't recognize anymore this database connection variable
        private DEAXIMAEntities db = new DEAXIMAEntities(); 
        private readonly string user = Environment.UserName;
        private string GetTitre() => "Bonjour " + db.UTILISATEUR.Find(user).UTILISATEUR_PRENOM;
       // private int dmCount = BaO.DemandesCount();
        private readonly int dmECCount = BaO.DemandesECCount();
    }
}
```

[image: Database connection variable Screenshot]

so i ended up getting this same error where it says **CS0246 C# The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)** [image: Errors list screenshot]

I've been trying to find the answer by looking at all the related questions on this forum but i haven't found the suitable solution yet.

PS: I'm a beginner in mvc asp .net so couldn't really figure it out by myself.
thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please avoid giving us screenshots of code.  Can you upload your connection string and code *as text*?  See [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) for more information.

Comment: You renamed the database, therefor your "database connnection variable" probably does not exist with the same name anymore.

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem with code, people who are volunteering to help need the text of the code. Images of the code are not an acceptable substitute.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: I've tried to add the relevant code as a text and sorry for the inconvenience.
thanks for the helping me to improve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the people looking for the answer in the future!

when i was remodifying the App.config in my application, i don't know why but the visual studio had emptied the .context.cs file(found it after expanding the .EDMX file) whhich made my database connection unfoundable. I somehow recovered all the code from the backup folder and pasted it in the same file. so that it can finally work  again without any errors.

thanks to all who helped me understand the problem and the concerned area in the project.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to Edmx file

2.expand edmx file & select .context.cs file -- double click

```
namespace DeAximaDataModel { 
  public partial class DEAXIMAEntities  : DbContext {
    public DEAXIMAEntities () : base("name=DEAXIMAEntities") // this name only u should give in controllers
    {

    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: I expanded the EDMX file but i don't find the .context.cs file. is it normal?
the files that it shows me after expanding the edmx file are : 
- .Context.tt
- .Designer.cs
- .edmx.diagram
- .tt

any help would be highly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: hi, expand context.tt -- u can able to see context.cs file -- expand context.cs file -- u can able to see this name "DEAXIMAEntities"

Comment: My Context.cs file was empty so I pasted the above code in context.cs and i rebuilt the project after closing and reopening the visual studio but the problem still persist! i don't understand what's still missing! thanks for your help though!

Comment: don't know the exact issue .... for my point of view on time of creating edmx .. ,tt,.cs file will created automatically.... those files are auto generated files.. may be u delete or change name